# Can't use function return value in write context in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Below code in controller shows the following error

> Can't use function return value in write context in yii2

Code:-

```
$sql = "select * from purchase_meta where status_manager=0 and po_id='p5' ";
$sql1 = \app\models\PurchaseMeta::findBySql($sql)->all();       
if(count($sql1)=0){
  $model =new  \app\models\PurchaseOrder();
  $model->purchase_status = 1 ;
  if ( $model->save() ){
   echo "save";
   exit();
  }else {
    print_r($model->getErrors());
    exit();
  }
}
```

how can i solve the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue:-

```
if(count($sql1)=0)  //is an assignment not a comparison
```

Change it to:-

```
if(count($sql1)==0)
```

Answer (score 1):

this line :

```
if(count($sql1)=0)
```

should be as follow :

```
if (count($sql1) == 0)
```

you would like to read more about the different between [comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) and [assignment operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php)